# Show print on console while using file attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print onto console while saving the same output in a file using the `file` attribute in the `print` call:

`print('hello world', file=out_file)`

However, this only writes to `out_file` and does not show anything on the console. I strictly want to use the `print` statement to avoid duplicating many strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an adapter that both prints to stdout and writes to a file:

```py
class Tee():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def write(self, text):
        with open(self.filename, 'at') as handle:
            handle.write(text)
        print(text, end='')

out_file = Tee('output.txt')
print('hello world', file=out_file)
print('good bye!', file=out_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom function, which prints to both

```
def myprint(str):
    file = open('print.txt','a+')
    print(str, file=file)
    print(str)
    file.close() #


myprint("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to provide the file name every time, and there is only specific file you want to write to, you can do this :

```
def print_(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', flush=False):
    print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, flush=flush)
    with open('yourfile.txt', mode='+a') as f:
        print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, flush=flush, file=f)
```

Or if you want to provide `file_name` for each `print_` call you can do :

```
def print_(file_name, *objects, sep=' ', end='\n', flush=False):
    print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, flush=flush, file=None)
    with open(file_name, mode='+a') as f:
        print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, flush=flush, file=f)
```